# Building an integration Api for two different systems

Tags: api, rest, system

Is there any way I could build an API which reads data from a third party system which doesn't provide an Api? I am planning to build an app for parents and I have no clue how the school management system of the school was made but I need to get data from it, is there any way I could get data by building my custom Api and not touching the school management system?

Comment: That would be blindly going in and finding data. Not exactly a guarantee for succes. Is there no way to contact the owners and/or creators of the software? It's impossible for anyone here to say how to get data from a system no one knows.

Answer (score 0):

By not touching the School management system. I understand by not accessing any of their resources like database etc.

We can think of using a web scraper that scrapes data from the school's website which scrapes data regularly and maintaining a database of its own.